# ADFS is sending AuthnRequest without a signature

Tags: adfs3.0

We have the following scenario:

- Site A (login portal)
- Site B (ADFS 3.0)
- Site C (Claims provider/IDP)

The user connects to Site A but needs to authenticate from Site B so the user gets redirected to Site B.

Site B however redirects the user one more time to Site C for authentication.

The AuthnRequest from Site A to Site B is signed.
The AuthnRequest from Site B to Site C is NOT being signed at all.

I can't find any settings in ADFS for this. Why doesn't ADFS sign the AuthnRequest it sends to the Claimsprovider?

Is it because of the metadata from the Claimsprovider?

Answer (score 0):

Normally it's the endpoint that specifies whether signing is required or not.

What does the CP metadata specify?

Comment: The CP has set SignedSamlRequestsRequired to true but its still not being signed. :/

Answer (score 0):

The request which adfs is sending to cp has to be signed, may i know which certificate will be used by adfs in this case?

In the a claim provider trust tab,you do get the option for certificate but that is required to decrpyt the claim, not to send a signed request.

Comment: What do you mean it has to be signed?